# How do I create a sound manager?

Tags: c++, audio, resource-management, entities

I have a basic entity system in place. Now I want to add audio. I want to make a database class that watches over entities, pulls data out of them, and creates audio streams whenever necessary.

I'm using C++ and SDL2. What is a simple approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way, assuming you have a bare bones component/entity/system architecture, is to create a Audio system and an AudioComponent. The AudioComponent would contain a reference (maybe just a string) to some audio and a corresponding "state" flag. As with other systems, the Audio system would scan entities, extract those that have an audio component and deal with the audio based on the state.

As you would likely need more than one audio snippet to be attached to an entity you could log these as a list of pairs; where the pair is a state and audio reference, but the rest still applies. You could put them in a map as well so there is a simple key lookup.

If you have a signals/events system later you can update the status of audio based on events; such as a collision. Although it might be better for the audio system at that point to just listen for events itself and extract only the audio source reference from the component.

The other method I can think is to forget the audio component altogether. This is a straight to the point implementation. Create an audio system that reacts to changes in entity states. For example, play a "hurt" sound when the players health drops compared to the last state and a death sound when it's suddenly 0.

Comment: This is very helpul, i will try it in a similar way. thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. Honestly, I would need some idea of how you set it up so far and a more specific idea of what you hope to accomplish in order to answer.

My best idea at the moment is create a base sound component with some way to retrieve sound information (`virtual sound_data getSound() =0;` as an example method). The constructer would add it to a list in a system somewhere, and that system would iterate through the list and get the sound data that way.

This isn't quite what you had in mind, but using messages or events to send information to an entity that generates sounds is probably a better idea.